# How to find all files that were modified since last backup with borgbackup?

Tags: filesystems, find, backup, borgbackup

I backup all my files (with borgbackup) every 2-3 months to an external harddisk I store off-site. The problem I want to solve is how to protect the files that changed since the last backup. These are probably not big and could be stored on a free tier cloud storage.

I was thinking: if should be possible to find all files that were changed since the last backup (maybe with `find` *all files newer than the file I `touch`ed after the last backup*), create a hardlink to a folder on my harddisk and backup this folder to the cloud.

Am I forgetting something? How would such a script look like? Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/):

You can use a find command to lookup files with a certain last changed date, like:

$ find /home/you/path -iname "*.txt" -mtime +60 -exec cat {} \;

where:

> /home/you/path

folder you're searching in

> -iname

name of the needed files

> -mtime

It returns list of file if the file was last accessed N*24 hours ago. For example to find file in last 2 months (60 days) you need to use -mtime +60 option.

> -exec

Excecute any linux command (here cat but you can do mv or scp)

You can also try to use [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for such goal.